# Facebook rewarded ads integration in flutter app for both ios and android

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, facebook-ads

I checked almost all the possibility for integrate the app with Facebook rewarded ads for my project.
I tried,

1. facebook_audience_network 1.0.1  : rewarded ads not supports for IOS in this package
2. audience_network 0.0.4 : Works in ios , But in android it throws an error.
3. easy_ads_flutter 1.0.6 : always shows the google ads only,

Due to the lack of knowledge I faced a ban from google regarding the ad count per time period, So I need an exact knowledge for integrate the facebook ad.

#In this code I have used the audience network package with a different version in the git,

```
audience network:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/marcellocamara/audience_network.git
      ref: master
```

The above code is works in ios , But on android getting error.

Any suggestion is appreciated and I need to implement the facebook rewarded ad in ios and android. In meta documentation the exact documentation of the flutter is not yet to be found.
The error I got when running the app in android, while using the audience_network plugin is below,

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(21286): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/Timeline(21286): Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:70399667
W/ActivityThread(21286): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@3f94727
D/ForceDarkHelper(21286): updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.example.sample activity: com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity@48f1a72
I/chatty  (21286): uid=10447(com.example.sample) identical 2 lines
D/ForceDarkHelper(21286): updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.example.sample activity: com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity@48f1a72
D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation(21286): IRenderScriptDevice::getService()
D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation(21286): IRenderScriptDevice::getService() returned 0x71555f38a0
D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation(21286): HIDL successfully loaded.
W/.example.sampl(21286): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioTrack;->getLatency()I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ExoPlayerImpl(21286): Init b7cd089 [ExoPlayerLib/2.8.4] [beryllium, POCO F1, Xiaomi, 29]
W/.example.sampl(21286): Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ActivityThread;->currentActivityThread()Landroid/app/ActivityThread; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/.example.sampl(21286): Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ActivityThread;->mActivities:Landroid/util/ArrayMap; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/.example.sampl(21286): Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord;->paused:Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/flutter (21286): 9001
I/flutter (21286): Ad could not be presented
W/VideoCapabilities(21286): Unsupported mime image/vnd.android.heic
W/VideoCapabilities(21286): Unsupported mime video/divx
W/VideoCapabilities(21286): Unsupported mime video/divx4
2
W/VideoCapabilities(21286): Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
W/VideoCapabilities(21286): Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
I/OMXClient(21286): IOmx service obtained
D/SurfaceUtils(21286): connecting to surface 0x71925dc010, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec(21286): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] setting surface generation to 21796865
D/SurfaceUtils(21286): disconnecting from surface 0x71925dc010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/SurfaceUtils(21286): connecting to surface 0x71925dc010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
I/ExtendedACodec(21286): setupVideoDecoder()
I/ExtendedACodec(21286): Decoder will be in frame by frame mode
D/SurfaceUtils(21286): set up nativeWindow 0x71925dc010 for 1280x720, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x20002900
W/Gralloc3(21286): allocator 3.x is not supported
I/OMXClient(21286): IOmx service obtained
2
I/ACodec  (21286): codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
W/ExtendedACodec(21286): Failed to get extension for extradata parameter
V/RenderScript(21286): Successfully loaded runtime: libRSDriver_adreno.so
D/        (21286): Successfully queried cache dir: /data/user_de/0/com.example.sample/code_cache
D/RenderScript(21286): Setting cache dir: /data/user_de/0/com.example.sample/code_cache
E/libc    (21286): Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.trace.perf"
D/AudioTrack(21286): set(sessionID=0)
D/AudioTrack(21286): set(): streamType -1, sampleRate 44100, format 0x1, channelMask 0x3, frameCount 14144, flags #0, notificationFrames 0, sessionId 0, transferType 3, uid -1, pid -1
```

## Here is the code throws error

```
import 'package:audience_network/audience_network.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}


class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    AudienceNetwork.init(
      testingId: "",
      testMode: true,
      iOSAdvertiserTrackingEnabled: true,
    ).then((value) {
      print('AudienceNetwork init $value');
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  

  void _incrementCounter() {
    final rewardedAd = RewardedAd(
      RewardedAd.testPlacementId,
    );
    rewardedAd.listener = RewardedAdListener(
      onLoaded: () {
        rewardedAd.show();
      },
      onVideoComplete: () {
        rewardedAd.destroy();
        print('Video completed');
      },
      onError: (code, message) {
        print(code);
        print(message);
      },
    );
    rewardedAd.load();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the below package solved my issue

```
audience_network:
git:
  url: https://github.com/varunkamanibosc/audience_network.git
  ref: master
```